# MFE module federation cannot find module for remote child import

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, craco

Im trying to build out a micro frontend for the first time so my main application can support a sub application. I have it all working when everything is just rendering App.tsx (remote) but as soon as I try and render a child within the remote application I get the `Cannot find module` error from webpack

Container craco.congig.js

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const CracoEsbuildPlugin = require('craco-esbuild');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    plugins: {
      add: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: "Dashboard",
          remotes: {
            DigitalCanopy: "DigitalCanopy@//localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js",
          },
          shared: {
            react: { 
              singleton: true, 
              strictVersion: true, 
              requiredVersion: deps['react'] 
            },
            "react-dom": { 
              singleton: true, 
              strictVersion: true, 
              requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'] 
            },
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
    ...
```

My remote craco.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const CracoEsbuildPlugin = require('craco-esbuild');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 3001
  },
  webpack: {
    plugins: {
      add: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: "DigitalCanopy",
          exposes: {
            "./DigitalCanopy": "./src/App.tsx",
          },
          filename: "remoteEntry.js",
          shared: {
            react: { singleton: true },
            "react-dom": { singleton: true },
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
    configure: (webpackConfig) => ({
      ...webpackConfig,
      output: {
        ...webpackConfig.output,
        publicPath: "auto",
      },
    }),
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoEsbuildPlugin,
      options: {
        esbuildLoaderOptions: {
          // Optional. Defaults to auto-detect loader.
          loader: 'tsx', // Set the value to 'tsx' if you use typescript
          target: 'es2018',
        },
        esbuildMinimizerOptions: {
          target: 'es2018',
          css: true, // if true, OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin will also be replaced by esbuild.
        },
        skipEsbuildJest: false, // Optional. Set to true if you want to use babel for jest tests,
        esbuildJestOptions: {
          loaders: {
            '.ts': 'ts',
            '.tsx': 'tsx',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

My remote App.tsx

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import App1 from './App1';

const baseTheme = createTheme({
    ...MUI THEME STUFF
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={baseTheme}>
      <div className="App">Digital Canopy App</div>;
      <App1 />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This works and renders fine until I try and render `<App1 />`

Then I get this error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App1' in ...`

Any ideas? I feel like this should just work. Importing children components from within the remote is pretty standard doesnt seem unique but I cannot find anything similar online which makes me think Im missing something obvious.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was missing the .tsx extension on the import. I have no idea why that is required by the sub application. My build configs are identical for typescript and my main app does not require that. I'll dig in and try and figure out why